# solver parameter 'test_iter' changes label values during test phase

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I'm using the [**Caffe**](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/) framework to construct and research convolutional neural networks.

I've discovered (what I believe to be) a bug by accident. *(I've already reported it on [Github](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/2524).)*

**This is the issue:** during the test phase, label values get changed depending on the value of `test_iter` parameter (defined in the solver `.prototxt` file).

---

I'm using 10240 images to train and test a network. Each image has 38 labels, each label can have two (0 or 1) values. I'm using the HDF5 file format to get my image data and labels into Caffe; each file stores 1024 images and their respective labels. *(I've checked the HDF5 files, everything is correct there.)*

I'm using 9216 (= 9 files) images for training and 1024 (= 1 file) for testing. My Nvidia 540M graphics card merely has 1GB of memory, which means I have to process in batch (usually 32 or 64 images per batch).

I'm using the following network to replicate the problem:

```
# in file "BugTest.prototxt"
name: "BugTest"
layer {
    name: "data"
    type: "HDF5Data"
    top: "data"
    top: "label"
    hdf5_data_param {
        source: "./convset_hdf5_train.txt"
        batch_size: 32
    }
    include {
        phase: TRAIN
    }
}
layer {
    name: "data"
    type: "HDF5Data"
    top: "data"
    top: "label"
    hdf5_data_param {
        source: "./convset_hdf5_test.txt"
        batch_size: 32
    }
    include {
        phase: TEST
    }
}
layer {
    name: "silence"
    type: "Silence"
    bottom: "data"
}
```

This network simply outputs all label values. I'm using the following solver for this network: *(Mostly copied from my real network.)*

```
# In file "BugTest_solver.prototxt"
net: "BugTest.prototxt"
test_iter: 32
test_interval: 200
base_lr: 0.0001
momentum: 0.90
weight_decay: 0.0005
lr_policy: "inv"
gamma: 0.0001
power: 0.75
display: 100
max_iter: 10000
snapshot: 5000
snapshot_prefix: "./bt"
solver_mode: GPU
```

The following results were obtained by changing the `batch_size` and `test_iter` parameters. According to [this](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/mnist.html#define-the-mnist-network) tutorial, `batch_size` of the test data and `test_iter` in the solver should balance out to make sure all test samples are used during testing. In my case, I'll make sure that `batch_size * test_iter = 1024`.

**These are my results when changing the values:**
`batch_size = 1024, test_iter = 1`: Everything is okay.
`batch_size = 512, test_iter = 2`: Labels that were '1' changed to '0.50'.
`batch_size = 256, test_iter = 4`: Labels that were '1' changed to '0.50' or '0.25'
`batch_size = 128, test_iter = 8`: Labels that were '1' changed to '0.50' or '0.25' or '0.125'
`[...]:` The pattern continues.

---

**What is going on that affects the values of the labels during testing?** Am I simply interpreting the use of `batch_size` and `test_iter` wrong, or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results shown in the output log are averages of the iterations, so if you have 2 iterations labels that are one are averaged to 0.5.

So, if batch size is 1024, you have 1024 outputs displayed and everything is ok. When batch size is 512, you only have 512 outputs displayed each is an *average* of two labels the `i`-th and the `i+512`-th label, most chances the labels do not co-inside.

To verify this, you can arrange your test data such that labels 1 are placed at even places, so when changing the batch_size the labels 1 still coincide and you should get exactly 1 for output.

Comment: Can I then safely assume everything is nice and unaltered during each iteration?

Comment: @MaartenBamelis you can trust Caffe. You might also want to consider Nvidia's [DIGITS](https://developer.nvidia.com/digits) interface: